# cannot convert from 'System.IO.StreamReader' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Tags: c#, gzip

I tried this piece of code:

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("mm.mdx");
        GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(sr, CompressionMode.Decompress);
```

I also tried `(Stream)sr` which makes the same error.

Comment: There's a complete code example for using GZipStream [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=net-5.0).

Comment: I'd expect casting `sr` to `Stream` to give a significantly different error. But if `mm.mdx` is compressed, you want to do it the other way round - create a stream to read the compressed file (e.g. with `File.OpenRead`), then a `GZipStream` to wrap that, then a `StreamReader` to wrap the `GZipStream`.